# How can we disable horizontal scroll in devexpress XtraScrollablecontrol

Tags: devexpress

In devexpress XtraScrollablecontrol I want only the vertical scroll bar. I don't want the horizantal scroll bar. How can we do that.

Answer (score 1):

`XScrollableControl` does not provide a way to hide a scrollbar.

See [Q392517 - "XtraScrollableControl make HorizontalScroll always invisible"](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q392517) in the DevExpress Support Center.

Answer (score 0):

Set `HorizontalScroll.Visible` to `false`.

Comment: I tried this. Still I am getting the Horizontal scroll. I want to remove it totally